# Update existing clusters to satisfy distance and volume constraints

Tags: clustering, optimization, algorithms

I have a massive distance matrix of clusters. The distance matrix is the distance between each cluster. I now need to recluster each entity based on two constraints. Each cluster has an associated volume.  The constraints are a max volume and min distance. I want to scan for the minimum distance and if neighbor cluster falls within this minimum distance AND if the summation of the volume does not exceed max volume, then that forms a new cluster. I want it to do this for all clusters. I’ve been struggling with creating an algorithm for this. Is there any algorithm that can help?

Comment: An EM approach utilizing Lagrange multipliers to formulate the constraints would seem to make sense to me.

Comment: This seems like it probably belongs on the [cs.SE] SE site, which has an `[optimization]` tag w/ 699 threads.

Comment: The problem that you defined is not really clear. What is the distance between two clusters (e.g. sum of distances between entities in them) and what is the volume of each cluster (e.g. number of entities in the cluster)?